# Scala error: Task not serializable, NotSerializableException: org.apache.log4j.Logger

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am a beginner of scala and get `Scala error: Task not serializable, NotSerializableException: org.apache.log4j.Logger` when I run this code. I used `@transient lazy val` and `object PSRecord extends Serializable`. Howerver, the problem can not be solved.

the code run on spark.

```
            object PSRecord extends Serializable{
                def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
                @transient
                val ss = ''
                val jobName = s"${PSRecord.getClass.getPackage.getName}" 
                @transient lazy val LOGGER: Logger = LogManager.getLogger(jobName)  
                val configuration = (taskConfigObj \\ "config").extract[PSConfigNew]
                FeatureThresholdNew.run(ss, date, configuration, LOGGER)
          }
        }
        
        object FeatureThresholdNew extends Serializable {
    
           import org.apache.log4j.{LogManager, Logger}
           
           def run(ss: SparkSession,  LOGGER: Logger): Unit = {
               Map(
                  "train" -> data,
                  "valid" -> data.filter($"hour".isin(hoursValid:_*))
                  ).foreach(
               mData => {
                     val numPartitions = if (mData._1.equals("train")) numTrainPartitions else numValidPartitions
                     val dfData = mData._2.select(...)
                     dfData.rdd.repartition(numPartitions).
                     mapPartitions(
                     partition => {
    
                       partition.map(
                       row => {
                              val features = localFeatureColumns.zipWithIndex.map(
                        col => {
    
                          LOGGER.info(s"#### col: ${col}")
    
    }
    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, To improve your question, you should simplify your code the the minimum failing scenario. There is a lot of content that are not related to your question. Also, I don't think it's relevant to your question, but where does the variable `data` come from?

Comment: Hi did you found the solution ? could you please post it if so ?

Answer (score 0):

In the piece of code

```
def run(ss: SparkSession,  LOGGER: Logger): Unit = {
  // [...]
  dfData.rdd
    .repartition(numPartitions)
    .mapPartitions{ partition =>
      partition.map{ row =>
        val features = localFeatureColumns.zipWithIndex.map{ col =>

          LOGGER.info(s"#### col: ${col}") // *** HERE ***
  }}};
}
```

You are using the `LOGGER` variable inside a map operation. That means the `LOGGER` instance has to be serialized and send the the worker nodes. And thus, the `Logger` class needs to be `Serializable`

Maybe you misunderstood the way lazy transient val works: it doesn't apply to the instance of Logger, but to the field `LOGGER` inside the class `PSRecord`. So If you serialize `PSRecord` it won't serialize the `LOGGER` field (which will then have value null).

Note 1:

Follow coding standard for clarity, variable should be in lower case. Also, I think we usually call the `SparkSession`, `sparkSession` or simply `spark` :)

Note 2:

If you need to send variables inside a map operation (of the likes), use broadcasting. It is faster and makes the distribution of data explicit in your code.